# Entity FrameWork Dynamic Where with OR Condition

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, lambda, unit-of-work

I just wonder how could I create a dynamic where with EntityFramwork. For example I need to build this query dynamically, but I have to check for a condition and it passed then concat the where, but will do an AND with the others conditions which I want an OR.
Here is my Example:

```
public IEnumerable<Data> GetAllData(Criteria searchCriteria)
{
var Query = this._repository.Retrieve();

if (searchCriteria.condition1)
{
    Query = Query.Where(p => (p.value1> 0 || p.value2 > 0));
}
if (searchCriteria.condition2)
{
    Query = Query.Where(p => (p.value3> 0 || p.value4 > 0));
}
if (searchCriteria.contition3)
{
    Query = Query.Where(p => (p.value5> 0 || p.value6 > 0));
}

return Query.Distinct().OrderBy(c=>c.ID).ToList();
}
```

This will return all the Data match with all the criteria, depending if it passed the condition or not. But I think this will be and AND, but I want returns all Data at least match with one condition, at least one.
Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: I dont think is wrong what I am trying to do...it is just a query builder...I would like to know how to build a list of funct to those pass the condition, make an or with them and add it to the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just allow GetAllData() to evaluate one condition, and call it multiple times for each condition you need to check? What you are trying to achieve means that your function will have more than one reason to change = hard to refactor and complicated to understand.

```
public IEnumerable<Data> GetAll(Func<Data, bool> criteria)
{
    var query = this._repository.Retrieve();
    return query.Where(t => criteria(t)).OrderBy(c => c.ID).ToList();
}
```

if you absolutely must process multiple conditions at the same time, pass in a `params Func<Data,bool>` parameter and iterate the array, concatenating the query as you go.

EDIT: Use deferred execution to filter out your data after retrieving it from the repository.

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        var query = this._repository.Retrieve();
        // Remove ToList so you can utilize deferred execution
        return query.Where(t => criteria(t)).OrderBy(c => c.ID); // .ToList();
    }

    var enumerable = GetAll();
    if(condition) 
         enumerable = enumerable.Where( ... )
    if(condition2) 
         enumerable = enumerable.Where( ... )
```

EDIT2 It seems your problem is not a question of technical know-how but a design problem. I suggest (after our discussion in the comments) you look into the [strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) design pattern and rethink how you are approaching this issue.

Comment: Bucause I have several conditions. From my home page I have some criterias and I pass the object with all the criteria, it is not just one. If you know what i mean...

Comment: I get you. Can I see the Criteria class?

Comment: I am going to assume that the booleans are your conditions, right?

Comment: Are all, I want to search by DistrictID, CountyID, etc...and also the booleans, and the int elements in the Theme..., specially the problem is with the nullable booleans because I want an Or between them if pass the condition...

Comment: Why can't you just get all the data and then reduce the enumerable as  you go along? Trying to do wizardry (which you are trying to do) and adding more than one reason for change in your functions is just going to cause problems when you inevitably have to chaneg something.

Comment: You mean return all the data and any of the conditionals? I am just building the where clause and when finish, execute with the tolist()..

Comment: Use GetAll() to get all of your data and then filter it by checking each boolean individually. It's less brittle.

Comment: yes I know what you mean, but it could have more than one conditions at same time. For example I want all Data that contains MediumLevelCycle or Secondary  amd so on..., and it is handle by checkboxes...

Comment: Then write functions on your criteria object to tell when you need certain filters applied instead of exposing the bools themselves. For example, if you wanted a filter to be applied based on Primary and Secondary being selected called PrimaryAndSecondary, then you could make a function that would check if they were both true on the criteria object and do `if(criteria.PrimaryAndSecondary()) enumerable = enumerable.Where( .... )` and apply the filter.